# How much water do you need for Netilat Yadayim?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, netilat-yadayim-washing, water, meal-seudah

When washing your hands for Netilat Yadayim, how much water do you need?

Comment: One and a half average eggs' volume.

Comment: Thanks but how does that equivalent to ounces?

Comment: http://eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=1097&article=4144

Comment: @yossi You don't have any eggs around? Why do you need ounces?

Answer (score 3):

*Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chayim* 4:6, says there's no minimum amount of water needed for washing before *shacharis* (or, by implication, before *mincha* or *maariv* or on arising).

*SA*, *OC* 160:13 ff., says you must have a *r'viis* of water to wash hands before a meal. The conversion rate of *r'viiyos* to milliliters (or fluid ounces) is a matter of dispute, but 90 milliliters or 3 fluid ounces is probably sufficient<sup>[1]</sup> if you have no reason (like your community's practice) to demand more. Please consult your rabbi for such reasons and, in general, for practical guidance, rather than relying on what you read on this site.

Of course, the water must also be sufficient in amount to wash the surface it's washing.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *Safek d'rabanan l'kula*.

Comment: Careful. You don't need to use the whole reviit, even though you must start with it.

Comment: @DoubleAA, quite right. Thanks. Edited to clarify.

Comment: I think it could still be clearer about how much water is required per hand (or if both are together) and how much is required to have originally been in the cup.

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's always a _r'viis_, isn't it? (E.g. _MB_ :67.) You wash your hands sequentially, you need a _r'viis_. You wash them together, you need a _r'viis_. Am I missing something? And if I'm not, then isn't that what my answer says?

Comment: @msh210 See for example MB :76. IIUC the cup must have a reviit, but if I use less than that to wash the whole area (twice in this case), then it works.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, I meant (in my last comment just above) the amount of water to start with. I can't check out _MB_ :76 at the moment but hope to later.

Comment: Consider also that it may be prudent to use a *r'vi'is* on each hand, so that [you don't have to be careful](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.93) about recontamination in certain ways (such as by getting contaminated water on the handles when there are other people in line to use the same *k'li*). Unfortunately, in my observation, some people who use less than a *r'vi'is* seem to be unmindful of this.

Comment: Note to myself for later or to anyone else who wishes to post another answer (or to edit mine): It's worth mentioning IMO that one should be generous with water when washing. (Not editing it in now because I can't source it now.) @Fred please by all means post the content of your comment as an answer (or edit mine). If anyone cares, I can make this answer "community wiki" so I get no reputation points for it.

Comment: @Fred Also, you would only have to wash once per hand. Totally worth it IMO.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, unless the hassle in drawing water from the local well is greater than that involved in using separate towels and frequently drying or rinsing the handles of the cup. | To follow up from my above comment, even getting the handles wet with clean water can create a hassle for the next person in line who might touch the wet handles before washing. A difference arises regarding the towel, though, as any subsequent person using that towel after Mr. Subr'vi'is may have just wasted their time washing and will perhaps be reciting a *b'racha l'vatala*.

Comment: @Fred, hardly a hassle, since it's hard to wash with much less than a _r'viis_ anyway IME.

Comment: @msh210 Is this [a good source](http://ateret4u.com/online/f_01975_part_12.html#סימןBקנחB-BדיניBנטילתBידיםBלסעודה-י) for using an abundant amount of water?

Comment: @msh210 Also, according to Yalqut Yosef, a revi`it is 81ml