# Water from washing that ran onto sleeves- Is it tumah?

Tags: halacha, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, netilat-yadayim-washing, water

If after raising hands for netilat yadayim the water from the hands ran down onto sleeves, is that water on the sleeves then rendered tumah?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31506/how-much-water-do-you-need-for-netilat-yadayim#comment81320_31516 Cf. Sh"A (OC 162:4), "שפך מים על ידו אחת ושפשפה בחברתה לא עלתה לו נטילה אפ' שפך באחרונה על שתי ידיו לפי שהמים ששפך על ידו אחת נטמאו וכששפשפה נטמאת חברתה ואין מים שניים מטהרים אלא המים שנטמאו מחמת היד עצמה ולא הבאים מחמת היד האחרת הלכך השופך מהכלי על ידו אחת ושפשף בחברתה צריך לנגב ידיו ולחזור וליטלם כראוי... לפיכך הנוטל ידיו צריך שישפוך... על כל אחת רביעית ואחר כך ישפשפם שהשופך רביעית כאחד אין צריך מים שניים לטהרם שעשו רביעית בב"א כמו טבילה שאין צריך שטיפה ב' פעמים".

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2020/02/04/negel-vaser-water/